# SQL Constraints on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm having difficulty in designing this table and the constraints for it.

I have a list of users, each user can have a list of preferred meals.  In an attempt to determine what meal is cooked next, I've assigned the lists values.

```
Yummy <- value 5.
OK <- value 3.
Disgusting <- value 1.
```

I only want each user to be able to mark each meal in one of the categories.

Currently I've an incredible simple db which is:

```
User(id, name)
Meal(id, name)
Yummy(id, userid, mealid) where userid id and mealid are foreign keys.
OK(id, userid, mealid) where userid id and mealid are foreign keys.
```

What i'd like to do is make it so that If I insert lasagne into `Yummy` then I can't also insert that value into `'OK'` or `'Disgusting'`.  I think that a constraint on both the mealid and the userid is possibly the right approach but I'm a little out of my depth.

Any help or suggestions would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Yummy, ok, disgusting are "Status"  maybe later you'll want a SUPERB or a Not fit for human consumption categories.  you don't want to add tables so a rating table makes sense.  Uueerodo has a good handle on the design to support this.  And it ensures a user meal can only be rated once.

Comment: @xQbert - yes, of course.  that does make sense and there may well be more tables to come which would be a pain to maintain.  I can't quite visualise the answer posted at the moment - running low on brain cycles :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably be better served with a database design similar to this:

```
user (id, name)
meal (id, name)
rating (id, name, value)
user_meal_rating (user_id, meal_id, rating_id) *primary key on (user_id, meal_id)*
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to reply! 

Following this model would I still be able to have multiple users choosing multiples meals but rating them differently? While not being able to have the meal in that users 'other' ratings.  Sorry for what might seem like a stupid question, I'm not visualising it very well.

The values I was associating with Yummy etc were going to be used programmatically rather than stored although storing them would certainly allow it to be changed quicker so that's also a better approach. :)

Comment: the primary key on (user_id, meal_id) will prevent any user from rating a meal twice, but allow different users to rate meals differently. One way to visualize `user_meal_rating` would be a grid where the columns are meals, the rows are users, and each cell holds a single rating.

Comment: Also, you technically have to store the ratings in the database; they could be values referencing a client-side enum (though then every implementation of a client would have to mirror the enum). Another alternative could just get rid of the "rating-name-value" concept and make rating a value from 1 to 10 where higher is better.

Comment: Ah, thank you, that makes perfect sense :)  Thank you so much

Comment: sorry to revive this but I have a question and was wondering if you could help.  Wiht the above design, is there any reason why I shouldn't have the name of the user and the name of the meal in the user_meal_rating table?

I figure I'll be using it a fair bit so could extract all i need from it instead of then going off to the user table with the id to get the name etc.

Comment: There is actually little reason to use things like names anywhere but the original table; and numerous reasons not to. If you were to use the user name in user_meal_rating; you'd: be taking more storage to store the name on every rating; actually make searching the table harder (with a unique id, it takes one comparison to determine if a row is one you are looking for, but it takes 4 comparisons to distinguish if a row is for "Josh" or "Jose"); make updating harder (if someone typo'd a name, it'd need changed everywhere).... and that is ignores you're likely to have more than one "John".

Comment: thank you.  I guess I was looking at it from the app perspective in that I'll need to extract that data one way or the other and making one call (to one table) felt like it might be more efficient but I see why isn't, thanks!